# c# string playlist to favorites copy modify

Tags: c#, .net, string, listbox

```
public string[] files, paths;
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames; // Save only the names
            paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames; // Save the full paths
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]); // Add songs to the listbox
            }
        }
    }
```

here listbox1(playlist) fill with open dialog box and listbox1 shows and working well with my player. i need a function move and copy to listbox2(favorites) with my string values coming from listbox1(playlist)

```
    public string[] files, paths;
```

also i need function to move and copy from new values listbox2(favorites) to playlist with my string files and paths

this is one mp3 player working with winddows 7 mediaplayer WMPLib library. i need functions to modify this two playlist mean with favorites and playlist ... 
thank you so much

```
public void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox files, ListBox files2)
    {
        ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sourceItems = files.SelectedItems;
        foreach (var Items in sourceItems)
        {
            files2.Items.Add(Items);
        }
        while (files.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            files.Items.Remove(files.SelectedItems[0]);
        }
    }
```

here button click

```
    MoveListBoxItems(listBox1, listBox2);
```

this function i use but not working when i exchance the list together first value of listbox1 working mean playing on player

here player

```
    private void listBox2_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[listBox2.SelectedIndex];
    }
```

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand your question.  You are showing us the code that works - can you show us the code that doesn't?  If you just want to copy an array of strings, then `string` is [immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) so you can use the Linq extension [`files.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to clone the array itself.

Comment: here i edit my message i need something exchange different values between listbox1 and 2 because when i move one song always playing listbox1 `public string[] files, paths;`

Comment: i want to exchange playlist and favorites list by select and then play with player both of them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, it's hard to understand your problem from your description, but it sounds as though you have listboxes that contain references to items whose data is stored in two separate arrays (file name and file path); you are putting entries from one of the two arrays into the listboxes (file name) and getting confused about the association between the selected items and the corresponding indices in the second array.

If you simply need to create arrays corresponding to the selected indices in `listBox1`, you can do this:

```
    var selectedFiles = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().Select(index => files[index]).ToArray();
    var selectedPaths = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().Select(index => paths[index]).ToArray();
```

However, a nicer solution would be to replace the pair of arrays with an array of classes representing all necessary data:

```
public class FileAndPath : IEquatable<FileAndPath>
{
    public FileAndPath(string file, string path)
    {
        this.File = file;
        this.Path = path;
    }

    public FileAndPath(string path)
    {
        File = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
        Path = path;
    }

    public string File { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return File == null ? string.Empty : File;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType())
            return false;
        var other = (FileAndPath)obj;
        return File == other.File && Path == other.Path;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int code = 0;
        if (File != null)
            code ^= File.GetHashCode();
        if (Path != null)
            code ^= Path.GetHashCode();
        return code;
    }

    #region IEquatable<FileAndPath> Members

    public bool Equals(FileAndPath other)
    {
        return Equals((object)other);
    }

    #endregion

    public static bool operator ==(FileAndPath first, FileAndPath second)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(first, second))
            return true;
        else if (object.ReferenceEquals(first, null))
            return false;
        return first.Equals(second);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(FileAndPath first, FileAndPath second)
    {
        return !(first == second);
    }
}
```

By overriding `ToString()`, you ensure that the file name is displayed in the list box.  By keeping the name and path together in a class, you ensure you never loose the association as items are moved between lists:

[image]

Your `MoveListBoxItems` becomes:

```
    public static void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox files1, ListBox files2)
    {
        var selections = files1.SelectedItems.Cast<FileAndPath>().ToList();
        foreach (var selection in selections)
        {
            files2.Items.Add(selection);
            files1.Items.Remove(selection);
        }
    }
```

`listBox2_MouseDoubleClick` becomes:

```
private void listBox2_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ((FileAndPath)listBox2.SelectedItem).Path;
}
```

And `button1_Click`:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames; // local variable only
        var paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames; // local variable only
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(new FileAndPath(files[i], paths[i])); // Add songs to the listbox
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much its working perfectly as i want ,, with this code i improve another functions. it's so help full for me this code thank you again ...